# Docker Symfony You have to enable opcache.load_comments=1

Tags: php, symfony, docker

Some time ago I got into one old project. I'm trying to use docker with it but when i come to localhost i got this error:

```
php.EMERGENCY: Uncaught Exception: You have to enable opcache.load_comments=1 or zend_optimizerplus.load_comments=1
```

I tried to google out this problem but i couldn't find the answer, maybe one of you had that problem before...
I generated Dockerfile from phpdocker.io/generator
Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM phpdockerio/php71-fpm:latest
WORKDIR "/application"

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install pcre-dev -y \
    && apt-get install libpcre3-dev -y \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install  php7.1-mysql php7.1-gd \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*
```

Answer (score 0):

`opcache.load_comments` directive influent how Zend VM
treat comment nodes. Since PHP 7.0.0 it removed.
More information about directive: http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.load-comments.

Also see: http://php.net/ChangeLog-7.php "OpCache section"

> Fixed bug #70022 (Crash with opcache using opcache.file_cache_only=1).
>   Removed opcache.load_comments configuration directive. Now doc
>   comments loading costs nothing and always enabled.

Your ways:

- use php less then 7.0.0 (for example `5-fpm` version
  https://hub.docker.com/_/php/)
- refactor legacy, may be your code contains something like `ini_get()`
  http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ini-get.php and you can find
  workaround solution and avoid this aspect usage.